# recorrer un array

Tags: php, array

Mi objetivo es recorrer y modificar $resultado para que tenga la suma de todos los números de $unArray. No encuentro la falla.

```
 <?php
    function bucles($unArray) {
      $resultado = 0;

       for ($i=0; count($unArray) ; $i++){    
         $resultado = $resultado + bucles[i];
      }
     return $resultado;
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: Nosotros tampoco encontramos la falla, ¿cuál es el problema?

Comment: Gracias, lo de llamar a i sin el símbolo $ no me había dado cuenta, donde no entiendo como quedaria es donde tengo que sumar  $unArray[i]

Comment: ya casi lo tienes tu mismo, esa variable que mencionas tiene el valor del arreglo de cada posición, por cada iteración que se hace sobre el array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No reinventes la rueda, usa la función nativa para la suma de todos los elementos de un array `array_sum($array)`.

Documentación y ejemplo: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-array_sum-function-2/

Comment: Si el op pregunta por como realizar un script de sumado, no veo muy correcto que la respuesta sea "usa este script que ya está hecho" porque así no responde su pregunta ni aprende el manejo de vectores que necesita

Answer (score 1):

Veo dos cosillas mal:

```
for ($i=0; count($unArray); $i++){
```

Aquí te faltaría poner `$i < count($unArray)`

Quedaría así:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($unArray); $i++){
```

Después a la hora de sumar cada elemento del `array` y almacenarlo en `$resultado`

En vez de :

```
$resultado = $resultado + bucles[i];
```

Seria así:

```
$resultado = $resultado + $unArray[i];
```

Pudiendo simplificar a esta manera:

```
 $resultado += $unArray[i];
```

Código completo de como quedaría:

```
<?php
    function bucles($unArray) {
        $resultado = 0;

        for ($i=0; $i < count($unArray) ; $i++){    
            $resultado = $resultado + $unArray[i]; // O  $resultado += $unArray[i];
        }
        return $resultado;
    }
?>
```